# Div set to back z-index if not position:absolute/fixed

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an issue, in my other site, this all works for me, but for my new one, it's not.  But here's my issue, I am trying to have different sections on my website, so I'm not setting the position to the sections with any value ex.  Top, left.  I'm not giving them a `postion:absolute` in CSS or anything, because I want them to "stack".

But right now, they are going behind everything on my website, as if there z-index is below the other ones, but it's definitely not with how much I've played with it.

Here is my code and, [click here for an UPDATED example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qSC7N/4/)

HTML

```
<div id="bg_reg"></div>
<div id="bg_blur"></div>  
<div id="section2">You can't see this div.</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#bg_blur").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
                $('#bg_blur').fadeIn(600);
            } else {
                $('#bg_blur').fadeOut(600);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

CSS

```
#section2{
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/white.jpg) #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
z-index:150;
} 
#bg_reg {
        background: url(../images/bg_reg.jpg) no-repeat right top;
        background-size: cover;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
        -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
        -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
        -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
        transition: opacity 500ms;
        z-index:0;
    }

    #bg_blur {
        background: url(../images/bg_blur.jpg) no-repeat right top;
        background-size: cover;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index:0;
    }
```

Probably a really stupid question and someone will know the answer easy, but I'm stumped.  Thanks for all help in advance!

**I now know z-index wont work on non-positioned elements, but how can I get this sites content working?   I have it working like I want on [This site](http://darrylhuffman.com) and I can't find out what I have done differently.

Comment: Please fix your fiddle, you did not turn on jQuery, see: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qSC7N/2

Comment: I noticed one thing, http://img577.imageshack.us/flvplayer.swf?f=Pge1wmhtenyxulebwsvhnph you shouldn't be doing this. parseInt your coordinates and check `if(newValue!=oldValue)` before changing styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure where you want `#section2` to appear, but to make it visible in the stacking order, simply set `position: relative` as follows:

```
#section2 {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    z-index:150;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/HM5Ct/

Setting `position: relative` keeps the element in the document flow and allows it to be rendered in the new stacking order along with the fixed and absolutely positioned elements.

Nice effect, good use of CSS3 technology! Keep up the good work.

Comment: this makes the charm!

Answer (score 0):

It is in the specification, a element **must be positioned** to have a z-index.

[CSS/Properties/z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

> Point, Note
>   Only works on positioned elements(position: absolute;, position: relative; or position: fixed;).

You need to apply `position: relative;` if you don't want to use `position: absolute;`.

---

You can also archive the same effect by applying negative z-index to the background, so you don't need to set any z-index or positioning to the other elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/qSC7N/5/

```
#bg_blur {
    background: url(http://s7.postimg.org/lyra1ksah/bg_blur.jpg) no-repeat right top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1; <-----
}
```

Source:

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index
- http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/z-index
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

---

**EDIT Based on comment**

On the page [darrylhuffman.com](http://darrylhuffman.com) you are using the same technique, but `#section1` still not visible.
The text inside the `#section1` inherit the `z-index:4` from its parent, and you applied `position:absolute;` to `#welcome` making it visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/UF9Bf/

```
<div id="section1">
    NOTICE THAT THIS TEXT IS NOT VISIBLE!
        <div id="welcome">
          THIS IS VISIBLE
            <center><span id="hdh">HELLO, MY NAME IS DARRYL HUFFMAN AND I</span>
            ...

#section1 { /*Still invisible*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}

#welcome {
    position: absolute; /* THIS MAKE THE TEXT VISIBLE */
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, but my other website, http://darrylhuffman.com works without z-index, yet I'm using the same principles.  Any idea's as to how I can show my content without using positioned?

Comment: No you applied `position:absolute` on the link mentioned, please read my answer again, and check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UF9Bf/